# Concatenate strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, string

I would like to concatenate two columns of strings into one string in a separate column as follows.

> ```
> A          B          C
> CIK:     007924     CIK:007924
> CIK:     009732     CIK:009732
> ```

but what happens is

> ```
> A          B          C
> CIK:     007924     =A1&B1
> CIK:     009732     =A1&B1
> ```

It does not evaluate.
I have tried:

> ```
> =A1+B1
> ="A1"+"B1"
> =CONCATENATE(A6,B6)
> ```

Which all do not evaluate. They just display these formulas as is.

Comment: Probably number formatting is set to "text" in that column. Set it to general, then re-enter the formula.

Comment: Do other formulas work?

Answer (score 4):

On the **Formulas** tab, can you check that **Show Formulas** option is not clicked? If it is clicked Excel does not evaluate the formulas, instead shows the formula's itself in the cells.
[image]